# How to vectorize this Python code

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, gaussian

I have the following code to calculate the normals of the weights and then the gaussian PDFs for these.

```
normals = []
for k in range(len(weights)):
    normals.append(multivariate_normal(mean=means[k],cov=covariances[k]))

gaussian_pdfs = []
for sample in img_descriptors:
    inside_array = np.array([])
    for g_k in normals:
        inside_array = np.append(inside_array, g_k.pdf(sample))
    gaussian_pdfs.append(inside_array)
```

Please help me in vectorizing the above code to achieve faster computations.

Comment: The first  that you can try is to preallocate `inside_array` or use `list` and then cast to array

Comment: i don't think that pdf is a vectorizable function

Comment: @RedEyed Could you please help me with how I can do that?

Comment: @bobrobbob Yes, pdf isn't a vectorizable function, hence I was looking for the alternative.